# Only the notebook built-in keyboad is changing the layout, not the external keyboard

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. After the installation I added the extra keyboard layout, but when I switch layouts only the built-in keyboard changes to the desired layout. The external keyboard remains with the en layout. Maybe it is because I installed Ubuntu with the external keyboard plugged. I don't know. That wouldn't be a problem if my built-in keyboard wasn't en layout and my external keyboard pt-br. Did anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: You may have encountered [bug #1899206](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1899206).